# Faster way to calculate distance between two 3D points

Tags: python, numpy

I have 4 lists of length 160000 as s, x, y, z.
I made a list(points) of 3d array of x,y,z.
I need to find the distance between all combinations of points for criteria and match the index of the points to that of list s, so that I get the s value of 2 points which satisfy it.
I'm using the code below.
Is there any faster way to do this?

```
import numpy as np

points = []
for i in range(len(xnew)):
    a = np.array((xnew[i],ynew[i],znew[i]))
    points.append(a)
for i in range(len(points)):
    for j in range(len(points)):
        d = np.sqrt(np.sum((points[i] - points[j]) ** 2))
        if d <= 4 and d >=3:
            print(s[i],s[j],d)
```

Comment: The first improvement you can make is to use the symmetric of sqrt, i.e. `d(i, j) = d(j,i)` so the inner loop can an iterate only j > i

Comment: You’ll want to check out https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html I don’t know your criteria, but if it’s something like “find the two points closest to each other” than this is the method you’re looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Idea is to use
[cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) and
[np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to vectorize the processing

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial.distance

# Distance between all pairs of points
d = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(points, points)
# Pairs within threshold
indexes = np.where(np.logical_and(d>=3, d<=4))

for i, j in indexes:
    if i < j: # since distance is symmetric, not reporting j, i
      print(s[i],s[j],d[i][j])
```

If d Matrix is too large to fit into memory, find the distance of each point to all other points

```
for i in range(len(points)):
    # Distance from point i to all other points
    d = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(points,[points[i]])
    # Points within threshold
    indexes = np.where(np.logical_and(d>=3, d<=4))
    
    for ind in indexes:
      if ind.size > 0:
        for j in ind:
          if i < j:   # since distance is symmetric, not reporting j, i
            print(s[i], s[j], d[j][0])
```

**Tests**

```
points = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1.1, 2.2, 3.3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [2, 3, 4]
]
s = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

*Output* (both methods)

```
2 3 3.4641016151377544
```

Answer (score 0):

```
points = np.array([x, y, z]).T                         

t1, t2 = np.triu_indices(len(points), k= 1)                  # triangular indices

p1 = points[t1]
p2 = points[t2]

d = p1 - p2                       # displacements from p1 to p2
d = np.linalg.norm(d, axis= -1)   # distances     from p1 to p2

mask = (3 <= d) & (d <= 4)
indx = np.where(mask)                     # indices where distance is between 4 and 3
```

```
ans = np.array([ s[t1[i]], s[t2[i]], d[i] ]).T
```

test run:

```
n = 10

x = np.random.randint(10, size= [n])          # dummy data
y = np.random.randint(10, size= [n])
z = np.random.randint(10, size= [n])

s = np.random.randint(10, size= [n])
```

after running the above code

```
points

>>> array([
       [9, 3, 5],
       [7, 8, 1],
       [0, 0, 2],
       [6, 7, 2],
       [4, 4, 3],
       [8, 0, 9],
       [5, 2, 6],
       [0, 8, 9],
       [2, 6, 9],
       [4, 8, 4]])
```

```
s

>>> array([4, 2, 9, 9, 8, 2, 7, 6, 0, 5])
```

```
for e in ans:
   print(*e)

>>> 9.0  8.0  3.7416573867739413
    9.0  5.0  3.0
    8.0  7.0  3.7416573867739413
```